# Error: Property 'buffer' cannot be accessed on 'ByteData?'

Tags: flutter, flutter-test

[image]

How to solve Error: Property 'buffer' cannot be accessed on 'ByteData?'

Comment: Did you try the solution suggested in the error itself (using `?.`)? - But the better way would be to check if `data` is `null` and decide what to do in that case. The error tells you it can be potentially `null` so you need to consider this case.

Comment: Looks like this is a Flutter problem, look the path